Does the definition of an ordered pair use concepts such as "left and right element"?
When we define ordered pair as a way to obtain one object (a, b) from two objects a and b, so that (a, b) satisfies:
$$(a, b) =(c, d) \iff a=c,  \quad b=d$$
But don't we say so that the left elemetns are equal and right too? So we use an undefined term in the definition. Is there a way to avoid it?

Why avoid it when you can just insert it into the definition, like this: For each ordered pair $(a,b)$, we define its "left element" to be $a$ and its "right element" to be $b$. After all, from this point of view, a definition is simply an entry in the mathematical dictionary. You can feel free to insert an entry where needed.
